# Why is a file present within my web application locally, but not present when the application is deployed to the web server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Please could you explain this concept I can't seem to get my head around...

Within a C# ASP.Net web application written in Visual Studio, I have added an XML file which is being read by the code. To add the file, I physically copied it into the relevant folder within my web application, and then in Visual Studio added a reference to it within an "xml" folder, which is in my "_resources" folder.

The C# code is accessing the XML file in the following way:

```
using System.Web.Hosting;

string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XMLFilePath"]);
```

The XMLFilePath value is set in the Web.config file as follows:

```
<add key="XMLFilePath" value="~/_resources/xml/anXMLFile.xml"/>
```

The file is successfully accessed when I'm testing locally. I then check it in, (into my source control system), then the application builds automatically on the web server. Then comes the problem... the file cannot be found and is not in the folder I would expect it to be in on the web server. If the automatic build is happening correctly, (which is quite a big if right now), am I right to assume that, as the file is present within the web application, it would then be present on the web server?

Comment: Are you sure that your build configuration is deploying the XML file? That's the first thing I would check.

Comment: Check the properties of the xml file (in VS) and make sure Copy to Output Directory setting is set to Copy if Newer

Comment: I'm not 100% sure no because its a newly implemented system which is currently having issues ironed out. I just want to know if other people agree with me... the file should be there.

Comment: Only if the property setting for the file are correct.

Comment: Thanks I'll try your suggestion Kevin.

Comment: Actually try patrykgliwinski's answer first, I think marking a file as content also makes VS copy it to the folder.

Comment: patrykgliwinski's solution worked! Great thanks so much!  "Copy if Newer" didn't work actually... this doesn't mean necessarily that you're not correct... it could just be not working for me... or perhaps the file has to exist already? Not sure, but I'm happy it now works anyway. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Right click the xml in Solution Explorer, go to *Properties* and make sure its *Build Action* is *Content*

Comment: Brilliant! It worked. Thanks for proving I've not gone completely mad. :-)